# prove that the sets $\{A_k\}$ are pairwise disjoint and that all numbers in $A_k$ are $\equiv (\frac{1}2 3^{k-1}, 3^{k-1}] \mod 3^{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> For a number n, write it in base three as $a_t\cdots a_2a_1$. Let $B$ be a positive integer and let $[B] = \{1,\cdots, B\}$. Construct the sets $A_1,A_2,\cdots$ inductively as follows. $A_1$ consists of all numbers that are at most $B$ for which $a_1 = 1$. For $k > 1, A_k$ consists of all numbers that are at most $B$ with $a_k = 0$ that weren't already placed in other sets (and that don't have $k$ zeroes at the end), together with the numbers satisfying $a_k = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ for $i < k$.

> 1. Prove that all the $A_k$'s are disjoint.
> 2. Prove that $A_k$ is the set of numbers in $[B]$ congruent to some integer in the interval $(\frac{1}2 3^{k-1}, 3^{k-1}]$ modulo $3^k$.
> 3. Prove (without brute force, of course) that when $B=40,$ the sets $A_1,\cdots, A_4$ contain exactly the numbers from $1$ to $40$.

For a digit a, let $a^{(k)}$ denote a concatenated with itself k times.

I think it might be easier to prove the first claim by induction. It would probably be easiest to figure out the "form" of the numbers that $A_k$ contains. By definition, $A_j$ doesn't contain any numbers whose base three representation ends in at least $k$ zeroes for $j \leq k$, so in particular, $A_k$ will include all numbers in $[B]$ ending in $10^{(k-1)}$ (since none of $A_1,\cdots, A_{k-1}$ will contain such numbers). But $A_k$ does not include any numbers ending in $20^{(k - 1)}$. I'm not sure how to form the inductive hypothesis from this though.

For 2, I think an inductive proof will also work, and 1 will be useful for proving this. The base case when $k=1$ is trivial.

For part 3, one can probably prove this easily using parts 1 and 2. Note that no number $\leq 40$ can end in more than $3$ zeroes, and the only number $\leq 40$ whose base 3 representation ends in $3$ zeroes is $1000_3$. So we just need to show that $A_1,\cdots, A_4$ contain all integers $\leq B$ with less than $3$ zeroes in their base $3$ representation.

Comment: Please explain why do you ask for the answer and when it appears you don't react? If the answer is correct, then it's good to vote it up. If not, it's nice to explain what is wrong. You started a bounty but it has gone.

Answer (score 1):

*Observation.* If $n=\overline{a_t\ldots a_{k+1}a_k\ldots a_1}_{(3)}$ then $n\equiv \overline{a_k\ldots a_1}_{(3)}\pmod{3^k}$.

[1] I wouldn't prove it by induction. Let $i<k$ and let $n\in A_k$. Therefore, from the definition of $A_k$, either (i) $a_k=1$ and $a_i=0$ for $i<k$ or (ii) $n\notin A_i$. If (i) holds then $n\notin A_i$, since it has $i$ zeroes at the end. If (ii) holds then also $n\notin A_i$. This shows that if $n\in A_k$ then $n\notin A_i$, which shows that $A_i\cap A_k=\emptyset$.

---

Now let's analyse the numbers of the specific form.

- [a] If $n$ ends with $1(0)^{k-1}$ then $n\in A_k$.
- [b] If $n$ ends with $0a_{j}a_{j-1}\ldots a_{k+1}2(0)^{k-1}$ where $a_{k+1},\ldots,a_j\neq 0$ then $n\in A^{j+1}$.
- [c] If $a_k=0$ and $a_{j}\neq 0$ for some $i<k$ then $n\in \bigcup_{j=1}^k A_j$. Indeed, if $n\notin A_j$ for $j<k$ then, from the definition of $A_k$, we have $n\in A_k$.
- [d] If $n\equiv r\pmod{3^k}$ and $0<r\leq r_k:=\frac 12(3^{k-1}-1)=0{\underbrace{111\ldots 1}_{k-1}}{}_{(3)}$ then $n\in \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} A_j$. Indeed, if $r=r_k$ then $n\in A_1$. If $r<r_1$ then let $i=\max\{j<k:a_j\neq 1\}$. Then $a_i=0$ (comparison of numbers in positional numeral system). If $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_{i-1}=0$ then $i<k-1$ and $n$ ends with $10^{(i)}$, so $n\in A_{i+1}$. If some of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i-1}$ are nonzero then from [c] we get $n\in A_i$.
- [e] Especially, from [1] we get that if $0<r\leq r_k$ then $n\notin A_k$.

[2] It's important to point out that $A_k$ *isn't* the set of *all* numbers in $[B]$ congruent to the numbers from a given interval. For example $7\in A_1$ so $7\notin A_3$, but $7\equiv 7\pmod 9$.

Observe that $A_1=\{n\in[B]:n\equiv 1\pmod 3\}$  and that $1\in (\frac 123^0,3^0]$.

Now let $k>1$ and $n\in A_k$. Let $n\equiv r\pmod{3^k}$ for $0\leq r<3^k$

- If $n\in A_k$ then $r\leq 3^{k-1}$ Indeed, if $a_k = 0$ then $r<3^{k-1}$. If $a_k=1$ then $r=3^{k-1}$.
- If $n\in A_k$ then $r>r_k$, so $r>\frac 123^{k-1}$. Indeed, if $r=0$ then $n$ ends with $0^{(k)}$ so $n\notin A_k$. If $0<r\leq r_k$ then $n\notin A_k$ (from [e])

[3] Observe that $40=1111_{(3)} = r_5$. Therefore $r$, the remainder $r$ modulo $3^5$ satisfies $0<r\leq r_5$. Then from [d], $n\in A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$. Since $A_i\subset [40]$, the theorem is proven.